# Function running twice can't figure out why

Tags: java, android

I'm calling a function, it enters, runs it and than calls it again dunno why, would probably say it's thread related

This is where I call my markerSettings function

```
  new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable () {
      @Override
      public void run () {
          MapsActivity.markerSettings(38.707925, -9.153079, "Almeida", "Working");
      }
  });
```

This is my makerSettings function that is running twice

```
public static void markerSettings (double lat, double lng, String name, String description){

    Marker almeida = (Marker) mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, lng)).title(name).snippet(description));
    almeida.setVisible(false);
    markerList.add(almeida);

    mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new
        GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
                for(Marker m:markerList){
                    m.setVisible(cameraPosition.zoom>15);
                    //8 here is your zoom level, you can set it as your need.
                }
            }
    });
};
```

markerSettings should only be running once, any ideas why is this happening and how can I resolve it?

Comment: You can throw a RunTimeException or run via debugger to find the issue

Comment: I already used the debugger, didn t find the reason for it to happen

Comment: maybe due to: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on where you put your new handler method

Answer (score 0):

I'm so dumb. Problem of working too much time in a row, I have a for (that is supposed to run twice) wich includes that thing that is running twice xD )